# IIS Windows Authentication using Federated Identities in Azure AD

Tags: azure, iis, active-directory, azure-active-directory, federated-identity

I am trying to make Windows Authentication (with Kerberos/NTLM) work in a Web App hosted in IIS using Azure AD Federated users but seems it does not work. Below are the whole infrastructure details:

- I have an Azure AD (e.g. skj.onmicrosoft.com) with Azure AD Domain Services Configured
- I have an on premises Windows AD (e.g. skjtest.com) which is federated with the Azure AD. The on-prem users are available in AAD, SSO works but the password hash is not synced with AAD.
- A VM is created in Azure and joined to the AAD Domain skj.onmicrosoft.com
- I created a Web App which uses Windows Authentication and hosted in IIS present in the above Azure VM
- When I try to login using an AAD user  (e.g. aaduser1@skj.onmicrosoft.com) to the web app, it works all fine using both Kerberos and NTLM
- However when I try to login using a federated identity (e.g. feduser1@skjtest.com), it fails showing a 401 Unauthorized Status code.

Here my question is, is this at all possible to make the Windows Auth (with Kerberos or NTLM) work with the Federated identities? If yes, please let me know the ways I can achieve this.

Comment: A key requirement for Azure AD Domain Services is that you do password hash sync. This is also reflected in the docu

Comment: @astaykov Our current security policy does not allow to sync the password hash, so do you think is it possible with the federated identities?